# Tag question: wow or world-of-warcraft

Tags: discussion, tags

Which is better? wow or world-of-warcraft?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tag: use acronyms or not?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-to-tag-use-acronyms-or-not)

Comment: FYI this is borderline moot for SEO; Google seems to expand "wow" in search terms to "world of warcraft".  All things equal from that side, rather go with the more readable one ("world of warcraft")

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably world-of-warcraft.

Comment: +1 Since it seems there are other game names that could get shortened and sound like World of Warcraft's acronym

Comment: @Jeff: any idea what SEO has to say about this?

Comment: Definitely the expanded version if it fits. We're going to run into things like the good ol' "PoR" situation that will require the expanded version, so it's better to be consistent on all cases. Only when you've got games like MMT, where it's unreasonable to fit the game title in a tag, would an abbreviation be better.

Comment: world-of-warcraft is more accessible to new players of the game, who may not be aware of the acronym "wow".

Answer (score 1):

Autocomplete makes typing `world-of-warcraft` easy enough. I think this makes the site more readable and accessible to newcomers.

If we do decide to go this way, perhaps we can get some kind of an autocorrect for common terms like WoW and CoD.

Answer (score 1):

My strict SEO head would say world-of-warcraft as it explicitly has both main keywords, but as a WoW player I know WoW is *very* heavily used as well. Certainly if I search Google for "WoW < search term >" then nearly every result is related to World of Warcraft, including almost always the top 5 results.

Comment: Of course that's Google magic behind your back. Nowadays I can basically search for **anything** and it will come back with something programming or WoW-related.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use both, which seems wrong.

Comment: "Use both" is not a good option for tagging. It's best to prefer one over the other and keep it consistent. Hopefully we will have a tag synonym function someday.

Answer (score -1):

wow

Since I abbreviate everything else too

Comment: I started with wow. I don't have a strong opinion.

Comment: WOW is nice until Warriors On Wrestlers becomes the next biggest hit and sells a billion copies, and then we have to deal with people mis-tagging.

Comment: Well then those guys will have to use warriors-on-wrestlers. Try http://www.wow.com ;-) The url is always right!

Comment: On the other hand: given SEO world-of-warcraft is probably more powerful