# badges on meta.*

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

meta.gaming shows 5 badges next to my name, which is correct, but gaming only shows 4. What's up?

Answer (score 3):

Badges are earned separately on Meta. Reputation carries over, badges are separate. Your 5th meta badge comes from you answering your own question [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/tag-question-wow-or-world-of-warcraft) (The Self Learner badge)

Comment: this is confusing at best.

Comment: Wait a second -- reputation carries over?!

Comment: @badp read the meta faq -- http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/faq