# Are game specific abbreviations sufficient in tags?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tag: use acronyms or not?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-to-tag-use-acronyms-or-not)

I've already almost had one vote to close on a question of mine because the person was unfamiliar with an abbreviation common to the game.  In this case it was MW2 (for Call of Duty Modern Warfare 2).

The question was tagged [cod] (which I changed to [call-of-duty] and [mw2].

My question pertains to the [mw2] tag.  Should we set the precedent of spelling out the common abbreviations like this one?  In this case [mw2] => [modern-warfare-2].

Seems to me that [mw2] is just going to keep popping up.

Comment: This is related to http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-to-tag-use-acronyms-or-not. I'm dancing between whether it's really just a subset question or if the matter of abbreviations here is enough to be a separate question...

Comment: Yep, let's call it a dupe.