# How to approach tagging for consoles/games with multiple names?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are various cases where a product can have two distinct names in different regions (such as the "Sega Megadrive", otherwise known as the "Sega Genesis") and some people might not be aware of both names.

How should a question relating to such a product be tagged?

Comment: tag synonyms!!!

Comment: I have just been introduced to the concept, which I have to say is a really good concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general scenario is that we do our tags in US English. So we would use [genesis].

I've been wanting to setup a synonym for the other name, but I couldn't remember if it was Megadrive or Megaengine or whathaveyou, so [thank you for clearing that up](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=genesis&sort=info). Basically, with synonyms, we'll have it that Megadrive maps to Genesis and there won't be any problem. The same goes for the majority of these scenarios.

For games, [I think case-by-case is important due to the sheer variety of scenarios possible](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165/tagging-games-that-have-more-than-one-title).

Comment: Super Famicon ftw

Comment: US English! meh :P

Comment: @Macha Wait till we get questions about red jewels in Illusion of Time.

Comment: I don't get it. Were the jewels a different colour in the different versions or something?

Comment: @Macha No, I just picked a random element from the game.