# Why was [game-recommendations] shortened to [game-rec]

Tags: discussion, tags, game-recommendations

Seems someone changed the [game-recommendations] tag to [game-rec] tag retroactively - i.e. not by manually going over each question.

Why is that? I think [game-rec] is very bad, as it's not clear what "rec" is. Is it short for "recommendation"? For "recreational"? Maybe it's a gaming genre I'm just not familiar with, something like "running empty corridors"?

I thought we [reached a conclusion that we should avoid short forms of tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-to-tag-use-acronyms-or-not), so I would like to understand what's the reason for shortening here. I'm not familiar with "rec" being a common English slang for "recommendation".

I propose that the tag be changed to [game-recommendation] (minus the final 's' in the previous version, though, that was odd).

Comment: Especially given that tags are auto-completed, what's the problem with extending rec to recommendation?

Comment: It is also similar to policy of other SE sites, like webapp-rec for example.

Comment: It stands for game records... ... ...

Answer (score 6):

I suggest changing `game-rec` to `recommendation` for the time being.

Rationale:

- I don't see why any tag here should ever have `game` in it. It's a *given* it's going to be about games!
- `rec` as a prefix could be `recommend` but also `recognise`, which makes it confusing <sub>(I was about to ask why do we have `identify-this-game` if we have `game-rec`comendation... oh wait).</sub>

Comment: For why we picked [game-recommendations] instead of [recommendation] before, see the comment exchange between myself and Noctrine at http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/217/looking-for-game-tag-vs-identify-this-game-tag/218#218.

Comment: Meh, @grace, peripheral recommendations are either still recommendation (but with the joystick/etc. tag) or another tag.

Answer (score 4):

From chat:

> **Ivo Flipse:** @Jeff did you change the
>   games-recommendation to games-rec?
>
> **Jeff Atwood:** yeah I hate
>   "recommendation" as a tag..

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57394/ability-to-create-group-of-lines-of-chat

Answer (score 4):

Two things

1. Recommendation is a poor concept on our sites. "Recommend me a computer to buy! Recommend me a game to play on my VIC-20!" So the presence of this tag is like a big "this question is very likely to suck" sticker slapped on it.
2. Recommendation is far, far too long as a tag. Recommendation is both "long and wide" -- it is a long word for # of letters and because the individual letters it contains in a proportional font are also wide.

   compare:

   IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
   MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM

   same # of letters.

Comment: Regarding (1) - that's a topic for a different question. Regarding (2) - I understand where you're coming from, but if I was a new user **I'd hesitate before picking game-rec as a tag, simply because I would not understand what it means**. And I think this situation is far worse than having a slightly long tag, especially compared with other tags here in gaming, many of which are game names which are anyway long. Maybe we should just go with [recommendation], without the "game-" part. It's shorter and still obvious.

Comment: @oak "I'd hesitate.." good, that is completely intentional, because we **don't want these kinds of questions anyway**. also note that we already have -rec tags on SU. So you're bucking convention here, and I'm very likely to overrule you: http://superuser.com/tags

Comment: 1. See, that's one of the cases where a [fourth place](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling) would come in handy...

Comment: Well, all my arguments got shot down once you pointed out that SU uses the -rec tags. Well, if this helps reduce the number of recommendation questions, I see it as an overall benefit.

Comment: Also, as proven in the title, "recommendation" is not easy to type right every time.

Comment: If you're looking for something not as wide, why not `game-suggestion`?

Comment: I'm not sure people hesitating to put any tag with the question is the right move. It seems to me that this will cause questions to simply come up mis-tagged, rather than not asked at all. "rec" is just not a clear abbreviation at all.

Comment: @Gnoupi, autocompletion ftw :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it seems almost asinine, but why not `game-recs` as a plural form?

- The questions inherently afford the
  suggestion of multiple titles / games
  that someone would like to play.
- It would reduce some (not all, though) of the ambiguity on what **rec** means. As Oak mentioned above, **rec** could be mistaken for recreational. This would deter that line of thought.