# How should we tag games in the Elder Scrolls series?

Tags: discussion, tags

Along the lines of [this recent discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2582/8366), how should we tag games in the Elder Scrolls series? Skyrim will be out soon (woo!), and we already have questions for Oblivion, Morrowind, and yes, even Daggerfall.

Currently, we have [the-elder-scrolls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls) for the series, which is fine, but for the individual games, we have more than a few questions that are tagged with both the series tag and the individual game tags: [oblivion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oblivion), [morrowind](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morrowind), or [daggerfall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daggerfall). Some of those questions had the series tag added, so I wanted to ask for a consensus before editing any more of them.

This is one of those series where I think the individual game names are very well known, but I think we also want to be as consistent as possible with our tagging.

How should we tag games in this series?

1. Both game and series tag, as some are tagged now. [the-elder-scrolls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls) [daggerfall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daggerfall)
2. Game tag only. [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim)
3. Game and series in a single tag. [elder-scrolls-morrowind](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-scrolls-morrowind) (23 characters, I believe)

If it's option 3, I think "elder-scrolls" makes the most sense: "tes" isn't going to be familiar to many visitors and "the-elder-scrolls" is too long. I'm personally inclined toward option 2 in this particular case, given the popularity of Oblivion and Morrowind, but I'll certainly abide by whatever the community decides.

Comment: I lean to option 3, but [tag:elder-scrolls-daggerfall] does not fit.

Comment: @CyberSkull, isn't that 24 characters?

Comment: so it does. I seem to have miscount. I just did a recount of [tag:elder-scrolls-*], and they all fit. I firmly support #3 now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand The Elder Scrolls game tags to include \[the-elder-scrolls\] prefix](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12844/expand-the-elder-scrolls-game-tags-to-include-the-elder-scrolls-prefix) (a more recent community consensus on the same topic)

Answer (score 3):

These games are hardly known by their series name, even among people who play them.  The acronym is all but unheard of.  I think that, in this case, the name of the game alone should suffice ([skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim), [oblivion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oblivion), [morrowind](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morrowind), [daggerfall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daggerfall)).  If the question is about the lore of the world they're set in, then [the-elder-scrolls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls) should be used.

Comment: But the series name is *[really important](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/9038258448/hey-bethesda-lets-settle-this)*!