# Expand The Elder Scrolls game tags to include [the-elder-scrolls] prefix

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

There was a previous meta request to [Rename [skyrim] → [elder-scrolls-skyrim]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3127/47878), but that was rejected because of two concerns:

- The 25 character tag limit would mean some games in the series would be too long.
- Search engine optimization may be compromised

I think that it's time to revisit these concerns.

### Character tag limit

The first concern is no longer relevant, since we have a 35 character tag limit, which is long enough for all games in the series (except *[The Elder Scrolls Adventures: Redguard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_Adventures:_Redguard)*, but we don't currently have any questions about that).

### Search engine optimization

I'm not sure that SEO is as big of a concern if we use the full game names. Right now, [searching for `skyrim`](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=skyrim) has about the same level of traffic as [searching for `The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim`](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=%2Fm%2F04gmzj). Furthermore, I get pretty much the same results in Google if I search for either term, suggesting there is some sort of synonymization going on.

### Consistency of Tags

Of course, one of the big benefits of renaming these will be that we will have consistent tags for all the games in the series. Anyone unfamiliar with the series knows that they are all related because they all start with `the-elder-scrolls`.

### Proposal

Therefore, I propose that we have all The Elder Scrolls games be tagged as follows:

- [the-elder-scrolls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls) → [the-elder-scrolls-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-series) (to be consistent with how other series tags work]
- [the-elder-scrolls-arena](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-arena) (already exists)
- [daggerfall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daggerfall) → [the-elder-scrolls-2-daggerfall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-2-daggerfall)
- [morrowind](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morrowind) → [the-elder-scrolls-3-morrowind](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-3-morrowind)
- [oblivion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oblivion) → [the-elder-scrolls-4-oblivion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-4-oblivion)
- [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) → [the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim)

  - [skyrim-dawnguard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-dawnguard) → [the-elder-scrolls-skyrim-dawnguard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-skyrim-dawnguard) (or [the-elder-scrolls-5-dawnguard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-5-dawnguard))*
  - [skyrim-hearthfire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-hearthfire) → [the-elder-scrolls-skyrim-hearthfire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-skyrim-hearthfire) (or [the-elder-scrolls-5-hearthfire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-5-hearthfire))*
  - [skyrim-dragonborn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-dragonborn) → [the-elder-scrolls-skyrim-dragonborn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-skyrim-dragonborn) (or [the-elder-scrolls-5-dragonborn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-5-dragonborn)*
- [the-elder-scrolls-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-legends) (already exists)
- [the-elder-scrolls-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-online) (already exists)

<sub>* Unlike the *Morrowind* and *Oblivion* expansions, the official name for these addons include both the number and the name "Skyrim", but adding both to the tag name exceeds the 35 character tag limit.</sub>

While we're at it, there are two tags for total conversion mods that probably should be renamed to their proper names, since they aren't "official" Skyrim addons.

- [Enderal: The Shards of Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enderal) [skyrim-enderal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-enderal) → [enderal-the-shards-of-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enderal-the-shards-of-order)
- [Falskaar](http://tes-mods.wikia.com/wiki/Falskaar) [skyrim-falskaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-falskaar) → [falskaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falskaar)

Of course, the old tags would remain as synonyms, but I think that the existing tag synonym [elder-scrolls-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-scrolls-skyrim) would be unnecessary.

### Request for feedback

Would it be okay to make these changes? Are there any concerns over something like this?

Comment: I have not played any of these games (because I'm lame - I assume), but would it make sense to discard the 'The' at the beginning? This would resolve all (current) cases where the tag limit would be exceeded by having the full name.

Comment: @Bob2Chiv I know that generally we eliminate the article words if the tag is too long, but I'm not sure if that's desirable here, given that all the main game tags fit, and it's just expansions that have problems. Personally, I'm attached to `the-elder-scrolls` instead of `elder-scrolls`, but I could see it going either way. Perhaps we could get some additional opinions?

Comment: I think the word "The" should be used since it is part of the official name, and the name just don't sound right without it, in my opinion. And, mostly, I am sure people search it by "The Elder Scrolls" and "TES" anyway.

Comment: Also, another thing, what of the tags for the extensions for Morrowind and Oblivion? Will they be included (considering they exist)?

Comment: @TheMattbat999 Right now, there aren’t any questions for those, but I think we’ll be okay because the expansion names for those games are shorter than Skyrim’s. E.g. [The Elder Scrolls III: Tribunal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_III:_Tribunal) → [the-elder-scrolls-3-tribunal] (28 chars) and [The Elder Scrolls IV: Shivering Isles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_IV:_Shivering_Isles) → [the-elder-scrolls-4-shivering-isles] (35 chars).

Comment: I saw this rename but held off on submitting because it has already been rejected once before. Glad to see a turnaround now that the tag length was increased.

Comment: Given that the subtags should always be used with the main game tag, I'm wondering whether we should bother to lengthen the subtags? We'd have all the necessary words in the tag box and in the meta info on the page from the main game tag. A subtag's main purpose is to allow easy filtering on a sub category within another tag. The main differentiator, the most important part of these subtags is the expansion name and it's being pushed to the end of quite a lengthy tag. I'm just not 100% sold that this is the right approach for subtags.

Comment: @Robotnik So what would be your suggestion for the subtags?

Comment: Leave them as-is?

Comment: @Robotnik I've thought about that a bit. Keeping the tags as `[skyrim-hearthfire]` etc seems to be different than the way we've been tagging expansions lately. For instance, the expansion packs for *The Sims* and *Civilization* franchises all have the full names of the parent games in their tags (e.g. [sims-3-supernatural], [civilization-4-bts], [warcraft-3-frozen-throne]).

Comment: Just my two cents, but I'm of the opinion that "the elder scrolls" (and perhaps sans "the") should be a tag, and the individual games should retain their own. I started playing at Morrowind, but "the elder scrolls" wasn't really a thing to me until Skyrim, when the whole world caught on.
Now it's an MMO. That being said, I think "The Elder Scrolls" should be retained for things dealing the concept of the ES world, but not specifically tied to each game. But hey, what's two cents these days?

Comment: @Asinine I agree about having a tag for the series as a whole, although I would prefer [the-elder-scrolls-series]. I think that when “The Elder Scrolls” name caught on is subjective to most gamers (for me it was Morrowind, for others Daggerfall). That said, I’m in favor of having all tags have the series’ full name. While [skyrim] might work, [arena] and [legends] won’t. For consistency, I’d rather just have [the-elder-scrolls-] prefix on all. Plus that helps those unfamiliar with the series to know what’s part of it.

Comment: @Robotnik While I'd still like to expand the names for the Skyrim expansions, I don't want to hold up the other games if that's the sticking point. Would you or another mod be okay renaming the Elder Scrolls tags and leaving the Skyrim expansions as-is if you would prefer not to rename them?

Comment: @Thunderforge - Sure. I just need to get like an hour to sit down and action a few of these. I already did [elder-scrolls-series] :-)

Comment: @Robotnik Do you mean `[the-elder-scrolls-series]`? Although your version would be a good synonym.

Comment: Related: [Retag request: The Elder Scrolls series](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15425/4797)  (retag to the official spellings of the game titles instead of replacing Roman numerals with Arabic numerals)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the state of these renames so far:

#### Game Tags

All base game tags and the series tag have been renamed:

- [the-elder-scrolls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls) → [the-elder-scrolls-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-series)
- [daggerfall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daggerfall) → [the-elder-scrolls-2-daggerfall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-2-daggerfall)
- [morrowind](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morrowind) → [the-elder-scrolls-3-morrowind](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-3-morrowind)
- [oblivion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oblivion) → [the-elder-scrolls-4-oblivion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-4-oblivion)
- [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) → [the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim)

#### Mod Tags

While Enderal does appear to be a 'new game' built on top of Skyrim, *Falskaar* doesn't appear to be the same - rather, it adds new story and a new area to the base game (much like some official expansions do) - it's closer to 'Unofficial DLC' than to 'Total Conversion'.

As such, I renamed the *Enderal* but left *Falskaar*:

- [skyrim-enderal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-enderal) → [enderal-the-shards-of-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enderal-the-shards-of-order)
- [skyrim-falskaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-falskaar)

#### Official DLC tags

As mentioned in the comments above, I'm not entirely convinced that expanding these is the right approach, given they should always be used with the base game tag anyway. Their purpose is more to provide a logical grouping of content. As such, these tags were left alone for now:

- [skyrim-dawnguard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-dawnguard)
- [skyrim-hearthfire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-hearthfire)
- [skyrim-dragonborn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-dragonborn)

However I'd be happy to action these at a later date if we get enough community support for the change.

Comment: Could you please add [status-completed] to this question?

Comment: If you consider it completed then yes. Only reason why I held off is because of the DLC tag discussion

Comment: Ah okay, I'm okay with the end result and would be willing to reopen another meta topic if we need to address it again in the future.