# Retag request: The Elder Scrolls series

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request, tag-synonyms

As per the meta post, [Should we standardize our tag formatting regarding Arabic vs. Roman numerals?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12181/should-we-standardize-our-tag-formatting-regarding-arabic-vs-roman-numerals), the official spelling of the game title should be used in the tags whenever possible, instead of replacing Roman numerals with Arabic numerals.

In line with that, requesting that these current tags be synonymized and merged to their official spelling counterparts:

- [the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim) → [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim)
- [the-elder-scrolls-4-oblivion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-4-oblivion) → [the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion)
- [the-elder-scrolls-3-morrowind](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-3-morrowind) → [the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind)
- [the-elder-scrolls-2-daggerfall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-2-daggerfall) → [the-elder-scrolls-ii-daggerfall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-ii-daggerfall)

I'd add this too but it [goes over the 35 character limit](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12510/4797): [skyrim-special-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-special-edition) → [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-special-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-special-edition) (42 characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems good. All done now.