# call-of-duty vs. call-of-duty-series

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a reason why the *Call of Duty* series tag is [call-of-duty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty) instead of [call-of-duty-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-series)?

It appears that [previous discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2582/21177) would prefer the latter. (It also appears that many of the currently listed questions don't need the series tag at all.)

Wouldn't it make sense to move series questions to the latter tag, and questions about the first game in the series to the former tag?

Answer (score 3):

Over the years, after a few meta discussions, retags and tag cleanups we ended up with *both* a [call-of-duty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty) and a [call-of-duty-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-series) tag. At some point a few years back I had updated the [call-of-duty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty) Tag Wiki to state that it should only be used for the original Call of Duty.

Today, when I looked I noticed there were only a couple of stragglers on the [call-of-duty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty) tag that I have since retagged appropriately. As such, moving forward:

- If you have a question about Call of Duty 1, use [call-of-duty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty)
- For the series as a whole, use [call-of-duty-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-series)

Answer (score 1):

While [game-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-series) might be the preference, it doesn't always need to be such. Consider [the-elder-scrolls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls), which we use instead of [the-elder-scrolls-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-series).

The `-series` distinction only need apply when there is no commonly accepted way to refer to the franchise. Call of Duty is unique in that it has a game of the same name, but since we're not getting questions on that 9-year-old game, and the franchise itself is Call-of-Duty, I see no compelling reason to change it for the sake of changing it.

Comment: Inevitably sometime in the next few years there will be a relaunch of the franchise with just the title 'Call of Duty', so that actually might be something to consider.  It seems to be the trend these days.

Comment: @Shinrai We'll cross that bridge when and if it comes.

Answer (score 0):

Should [call-of-duty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty) (referring to the original call of duty) be renamed [call-of-duty-original](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-original) or [call-of-duty-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-1)?

Thing is if they do a move like battlefield, that released a [battlefield-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefield-1), we would have to rename the tag again.

Comment: In previous instances we've appended the year of release to the new games tag (e.g. [tag:ratchet-and-clank-2016]). I'd rather wait if/until it happens and we can cross that bridge then. For now, the tags are being used as intended.